Shifting phase with boolean logic gate
Given 4 foundational identical square wave with different phases:

Yellow: (Ground/Phase Reference)
Cyan: 45 degree relative to Yellow
Purple: 90 degree relative to Yellow (a.k.a. the quadrature version of Yellow)
Green: 135 degree relative to Yellow


How do I shift unknown arbitrary square signal based on those 4 foundational square signal?
For example, the arbitrary signal is the cyan (in this case I pretend to don't know the phase of cyan is 45 degree relative to yellow)

If I perform an operator X once, it will shift (+45) to 90 degree relative to yellow (equivalent to purple)
shifting the same operator X, will shift to 135 degree relative to yellow (equivalent to green)
shifting it again 3rd, will shift to 180 degree relative to yellow (logical NOT of yellow)
shifting it again 4th, will shift to 225 degree relative to yellow (logical NOT of cyan itself)
shifting it again 5th, will shift to 270 degree relative to yellow (logical NOT of purple)
shifting it again 6th, will shift to 315 degree relative to yellow (logical NOT of green)

The only allowed operator is boolean operator, such as AND, OR, XOR, NOR, NOT, XNOR, IMPLY, NIMPLY. So I would expect the interference between 4 signals using those operator only.

Input: a square signal with unknown phase
Output: +45 shift version of input signal
Operator: X (performing +45 signal)
Phase Reference for measure: Yellow (0 degree phase)

E.g. Performing OR interference between green and purple yielding new square signal with higher PWM instead of default 50%. But PWM manipulation is another topic, but perhaps it can be useful for the operator defintion which I expect the phase shifting. Let's give the name of operator/function as SHIFT_45(INPUT)
Here is the clue, how CYAN, PURPLE, and GREEN come from the yellow signal:


Is this a homework problem ? Is the phase of the input really arbitrary or an integer multiple of 45 degrees?

@Hilmar no, this is not homework, I'm trying to emulate quantum computing in classical digital system. The phase of input is really arbitrary, but the expected output is shifted 45 degree of input, so the function doesn't know the phase of input unless the input know the phase reference which is I define yellow as relative phase.
So, allowed known signal to include in function is Y, C, P, G. E.g. performing G OR P resulting new higher PWM signal, but this doesn't solve the problem.

@Hilmar yes the phase of arbitrary always factor of 45

you say "unknown" square wave, is the frequency hence also unknown?

@MarcusMüller The frequency is also relative to yellow. Yellow is the ground of phase, period, and frequency, so the unit of frequency is not per seconds, but per period of yellow . Which means, the duration of signal doesn't matter here.
Since i'm using 8x prescaler, the maximum frequency of possible is the square wave with frequency of 4 square waves per yellow period.

So, to conclude: 1. the frequency of the input signal is "1", "2", "3" or "4", where the frequency of the yellow wave is "1". and 2. The phase of the input signal is one of $0\cdot,1\cdot,2\cdot,\ldots,7 \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$, where the yellow signal has phase 0.

(note that words like "unknown" and "arbitrary" are at least colloquially pretty different to "quantized to multiples of 45°", so I was first very confused, hence my request: can you confirm that what I wrote above is 100% correct?)

@MarcusMüller I'm sorry for the confussion, I have bad grammar and trying to better for the wording used. I will edit and use ChatGPT later.

PLEASE don't use ChatGPT. Write what you mean. ChatGPT will make things harder to understand and write things you don't mean. We are here to help! Just write it as you want to. Do you understand my comment that I asked you to confirm (yes/no)?

@MarcusMüller Yes, both all correct for all possible phase and frequency. There are 8 total possible phases and 4 possible frequency.

Using these conventions:


the frequency of the input signal is "1", "2", "3" or "4", where the frequency of the yellow wave is "1". and
The phase of the input signal is one of 0⋅,1⋅,2⋅,…,7⋅π/2, where the yellow signal has phase 0


Let's start with the highest-frequency signal: f=4. To delay that by 45°, you would need a delay that is 1/4 of that wave's period, so 1/16 of the reference period.
But that's shorter than any period that you can get by logically combining your four input signal.
So, first thing you need is a frequency synthesizer that synthesizes a sufficiently fast clock. You can implement that however you want – the only condition is that there's a rising edge that coincides with the yellow rising edge. Hence, a VCO and a simple PLL will do – but a VCO is not a logic gate, so this is impossible to do within the framework you're giving yourself.
So, you can conclude here that it's impossible, and stop. Or you loosen your restrictions that you can only use logic gates.
Assuming you have a clock that runs at a period of "shortest possible delay necessary" (i.e. at frequency 4·4=16), call it "high speed clock" (HSC), you realize that depending on your input square wave's frequency, you need to delay that input by 1, 2, 3 or 4 of the periods of that wave.
And the phase of the input wave doesn't matter at all – all that matters is the frequency, because that selects whether you delay by 1, 2, 3 or 4.
To determine the frequency, you can simply count the edges of HSC) between two edges of the input. Whether it's 1, 2, 3, or 4 defines the delay.
You then use that knowledge and build a delay chain (that's D flip flops, in a chain, where you select the output of the  1., 2., 3., or 4. flip flop depending on your count.
And that's it.
So, to conclude:

synthesize your HSC from your yellow wave. $f_{\text{HSC}} = 16, \phi_{\text{HSC}} = 0$.
build a 2-bit counter, triggered on HSC ⤴ (rising edge only), reset on input wave edge ⤴, count "latched" into two D-flip flops (A, B) on input wave ⤵ (falling edge only).
build a four-stage shift register out of D-flip flops (C, D, E, and F) clocked on HSC ⤴. Input connected to input signal.
build a mux out of logic gates that selects the output of the C, D, E, or F flip flop based on the state of (A, B).

That's it. As you can see, none of your cyan, purple or green square waves were any useful in this. You could use them for the PLL that generates HSC from yellow, but since they are themselves generated from yellow, that's a bad idea, since it would not decrease jitter.

Thanks for the answer, but is it only apply to square wave with arbitrary PWM? I mean, are you restricting the answer with 50% PWM square wave signal only?

PLL and VCO a bit too low level for me as computer engineering background, I couldn't generate HSC, it's the physical limitation in computer engineering perspective. So, what I did, is using the fastest frequency clock as HSC (clock ground) then use that for prescaling with JKFF or DFF for another clock with lower rate. So, in short I need atleast four-stage shift register as prescaler overall?

yes, but that is literally what "square wave" means :)

if I say "the minimum clock you need is f=X", and then you go with less than X, how do you propose that is compatible with "minimum"

and if you can't synthesize a clock (or have some other analog component to shift by ¼ of the shortest period existing in your whole system), then this problem is impossible to solve, as explained in my first paragraph. End of story.
